# for loop optimization c ++

Tags: c++, optimization

this is my first time posting in this site and I hope I get some help/hint. I have an assignment where I need to optimize the performance to the inner for loop but I have no idea how to do that. the code was given in the assignment. I need to count the time(which I was able to do) and improve the performance.

### Here is the code:

```
//header files

#define N_TIMES     200   //This is originally 200000 but changed it to test the          program faster    
#define ARRAY_SIZE    9973

int main (void) {
  int  *array = (int*)calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  int  sum = 0;
  int  checksum = 0;
  int  i;
  int  j;
  int  x; 

  // Initialize the array with random values 0 to 13. 
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {    
    x = rand() / (int)(((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1) / 14);
    array[j] = x;
    checksum += x;
  }
  //printf("Checksum is %d.\n",checksum);

  for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
    // Do not alter anything above this line.
    // Need to optimize this for loop----------------------------------------
    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
      sum += array[j];
      printf("Sum is now: %d\n",sum);
    }


    // Do not alter anything below this line.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    // Check each iteration.  
    //
    if (sum != checksum) {
      printf("Checksum error!\n");
    }
    sum = 0;

  } 
  return 0;
}
```

The code takes about 695 seconds to run. Any help on how to optimize it please?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Move the printing outside the loop - it's by far the costliest operation in that loop.

Comment: there isn't much to optimize, how long does it take if you remove the printf statement?

Comment: Tell the compiler to optimize it. With gcc that means `g++ -O3 [other stuff]`. Seriously until you have explored the compiler's abilities thinking about how *you* are going to optimize is silly to the point that it borders on stupid.

Answer (score 3):

The bottleneck in that loop is obviously the IO done by `printf`; since you are probably writing the output on a console, the output is line buffered, which means that the stdio buffer is flushed at each iteration, which slows down things a lot.

If you *have* to do all that prints, you can greatly enhance the performance by forcing the stream to do block buffering: before the `for` add a

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 0);
```

In alternative, if this approach is not considered valid, you can do your own buffering by allocating a big buffer on your own and do your own buffering: write in your buffer using `sprintf`, periodically emptying it in the output stream with a `fwrite`.

Also, you can use the poor man's approach to buffering - just use a buffer big enough to write all that stuff (you can calculate how big it must be quite easily) and write in it without worrying about when it's full, when to empty it, ... - just empty it at the end of the loop. *edit: see @paxdiablo's answer for an example of this*

---

Applying just the first optimization, what I get with `time` is

```
real    0m6.580s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m2.400s
```

vs the original

```
real    0m8.451s
user    0m0.700s
sys     0m3.156s
```

So, we got down of ~3 seconds in real time, half a second in user time and ~0.7 seconds in system time. But what we can see here is the huge difference between user+sys and real, which means that the time is not spent in doing something inside the process, but waiting.

Thus, **the real bottleneck here is not in our process, but in the process of the virtual terminal emulator**: sending huge quantities of text to the console **is going to be slow no matter what optimizations we do in our program**; in other words, your task is not CPU-bound, but IO-bound, so CPU-targeted optimizations won't be of much benefit, since at the end you have to wait anyway for your IO device to do his slow stuff.

The real way to speed up such a program would be much simpler: avoid the slow IO device (the console) and just write the data to file (which, by the way, is block-buffered by default).

```
matteo@teokubuntu:~/cpp/test$ time ./a.out > test

real    0m0.369s
user    0m0.240s
sys     0m0.068s
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there's absolutely no variation in that loop based on `i` (the outer loop), you don't need to calculate it each time.

In addition, the printing of the data should be *outside* the inner loop so as not to impose I/O costs on the calculation.

With those two things in mind, one possibility is:

```
static int sumCalculated = 0;
if (!sumCalculated) {
    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }
    sumCalculated = 1;
}
printf("Sum is now: %d\n",sum);
```

although that has different output to the original which may be an issue (one line at the end rather than one line per addition).

If you *do* need to print the accumulating sum within the loop, I'd simply buffer that as well (since it doesn't vary each time through the `i` loop.

The string `Sum is now: 999999999999\n` (12 digits, it may vary depending on your `int` size) takes up 25 bytes (excluding terminating NUL). Multiply that by 9973 and you need a buffer of about 250K (including a terminating NUL). So something like this:

```
static char buff[250000];
static int sumCalculated = 0;

if (!sumCalculated) {
    int offset = 0;
    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
        offset += sprintf (buff[offset], "Sum is now: %d\n",sum);
    }
    sumCalculated = 1;
}
printf ("%s", buff);
```

Now that sort of defeats the whole intent of the outer loop as a benchmark tool but loop-invariant removal is a valid approach to optimisation.

Comment: Uhm, this won't work, at each iteration of the outer loop `sumCalculated` is reinitialized; also, I think that the "sum is now" message *has* to be printed inside the loop (the optimized program wouldn't give the same output of the original).

Comment: @Matteo, the `static` fixes that. I'll update for your second point.

Answer (score 0):

Move the printf outside the for loop.

```
   // Do not alter anything above this line.
   //Need to optimize this for loop----------------------------------------
    for (j=0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }
   printf("Sum is now: %d\n",sum);

    // Do not alter anything below this line.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: But that, obviously, does something different. If he wants it to print every pass then this is wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for these tips. moving printif outside the loop didn't give the same output as before. Also, I'm not allowed to use the IDE optimizations futures. I'm trying to figure out how to use Unrolling loop. I read some samples online but can't get it to work yet!

Comment: @samy: loop unrolling and similar optimizations is not going to help, since your task is IO bound, not CPU bound. You can trim away some "fat" from the IO using buffering, but the real problem is that the device on which you are doing IO (the console) is really slow, and no amount of optimizations in your code can overcome this fact.

Comment: Hi Matteo, I agree with you but the point of the assignment is to compare the performance of the program before and after optimizing it on the same machine.

Comment: @samy: if you ask me, I think that the point of this exercise is to understand that an IO-bound task is substantially unaffected by CPU-targeted optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Getting the I/O out of the loop is a big help.
2. Depending on the compiler and machine, you *might* get a tiny increase in speed by using pointers rather than indexing (though on modern hardware, it generally doesn't make a difference).
3. Loop unrolling might help to increase the ratio of useful work to loop overhead.
4. You could use vector instructions (e.g., SIMD) to do a bunch of calculation in parallel.
5. Are you allowed to pack the array?  Can you use an array of a smaller type than int (given that all the values are very small)?  Making the array physically shorter improves locality.

Loop unrolling might look something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j += 2) {
  sum += array[j] + array[j+1];
}
```

You'd have to figure out what to do if the array isn't an exact multiple of the unrolling size (which is probably why the assignment uses a prime number).

You would have to experiment to see how much unrolling would be the right amount.